# Mean of a column in a data frame, given the column's name

Tags: r, mean

I'm inside a big function I have to write. In the last part I have to calculate the mean of a column in a data frame. The name of the column I am operating on is given as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 42):

I think you're asking how to compute the mean of a variable in a data frame, given the name of the column. There are two typical approaches to doing this, one indexing with `[[` and the other indexing with `[`:

```
data(iris)
mean(iris[["Petal.Length"]])
# [1] 3.758
mean(iris[,"Petal.Length"])
# [1] 3.758
mean(iris[["Sepal.Width"]])
# [1] 3.057333
mean(iris[,"Sepal.Width"])
# [1] 3.057333
```

Answer (score 19):

if your column contain any value that you want to neglect. it will help you

```
## da is data frame & Ozone is column name 

##for single column
mean(da$Ozone, na.rm = TRUE)  

##for all columns
colMeans(x=da, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 18):

Any of the following should work!!

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:3,y=4:6)

mean(df$x)
mean(df[,1])
mean(df[["x"]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `summarise` in the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
summarise(df, Average = mean(col_name, na.rm = T))
```

note: `dplyr` supports both `summarise` and `summarize`.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are being asked to do (or perhaps asking yourself?)  is take a character value which matches the name of a column in a particular dataframe (possibly also given as a character). There are two tricks here. Most people learn to extract columns with the "$" operator and that won't work inside a function if the function is passed a character vecor. If the function is also supposed to accept character argument then you will need to use the `get` function as well:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20)
 mean_col <- function( dfrm, col ) mean( get(dfrm)[[ col ]] )
 mean_col("df1", "b")
 # [1] 15.5
```

There is sort of a semantic boundary between ordinary objects like character vectors and language objects like the names of objects. The `get` function is one of the functions that lets you "promote" character values to language level evaluation. And the "$" function will NOT evaluate its argument in a function, so you need to use"[[". "$" only is useful at the console level and needs to be completely avoided in functions.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a data frame(say df) with columns "x" and "y", you can find mean of column (x or y) using:

**1**.Using **mean()** function

```
z<-mean(df$x)
```

**2**.Using the **column name(say x) as a variable** using `attach()` function

```
 attach(df)
 mean(x)
```

When done you can call `detach()` to remove "x"

```
detach()
```

**3**.Using `with()` function, it lets you use columns of data frame as distinct variables.

```
 z<-with(df,mean(x))
```