# Argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA Table with one column

Tags: r

I've been searching other related questions but nome works for me.
I'm totally new on R so please, speak to me like I'm 5. Also, english is not my first language.
Now. I made a list on excel. Values between 2000 and 4000 and a header. My Dataset is named "Ejercicio 2.4".

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naLNB.jpg)

Just a simple list.
Then, I imported the dataset to R like this:

[Import Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkVoE.jpg)

I used the `summary(Ejercicio_2_4)` function to obtain simple stathistical data, but I wanted to usethe `mean(Ejercicio_2_4)` and I got the following message:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(Ejercicio_2_4) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

[Warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEE3G.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want the mean of the dataframe column, not the mean of the dataframe itself. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163863/r-need-help-to-calculate-the-mean-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame) for example. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry. Pictures of data and/or code are generally viewed with extreme annoyance on SO. Learn to post MCVE with text in the body of the question

Comment: Sorry, first time poting here. I'll try to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Florian comment...

```
 mean(Ejercicio_2_4$Birthweight)
```

or

```
colMeans(Ejercicio_2_4)
```