# How to reference a variable in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, data.table

I am looping through different data.tables and the variables in the data.table. But I'm having trouble referencing the variables inside of the `for` loop

```
dt1 <- data.table(a1 = c(1,2,3), a2 = c(4,5,2))
dt2 <- data.table(a1 = c(1,43,1), a2 = c(52,4,1))
```

For each datatable, I want to find the average of each variable for observations where that variable != 1. Below is my attempt which doesn't work:

```
dtname = 'dt'
ind  = c('1', '2')
for (d in ind) {
  df <- get(paste0('dt', d, sep=''))
  for (v in ind) {
    varname <- paste0('a', v, sep='')
    df1 <- df %>%
      filter(varname!=1) %>%
      summarise(varname = mean(varname))
    print(df1)
    }
   }
```

The desired output is to take and print the average of a1 = c(2,3) in dt1, the average of a2 = (4,5,2) in dt1, the average of a1 = c(43) in dt2, the average of a2 = c(54,4) in dt2.

What am I doing wrong here? In general, how should I reference a variable inside of a `for` loop (varname) that is pieced together by using the looping index (v) and something else?

Comment: Why are you mixing `data.table` syntax with `dplyr`/verse syntax? If you want to work with data.tables, you should really learn about how to do this. Otherwise, it's pointless to have them around. Something like `df1 <- df[varname!=1, .(varname = mean(varname))]` for the body of your loop with `data.table`, but you can probably do this much easier. You should probably show your desired output. Also look into [lists of data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames).

Comment: well done for posting an example data. It is not really clear to me what you are looking to achieve. It sounds like something that can easily be done using a vectorised R-approach. A desired output would help

Comment: Tjebo I just added the desired output

Comment: @Imo I tried      df1 <- df[varname!=1, .(varname = mean(varname))]  but got the following error   "In mean.default(varname) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA". The problem is that inside the for loop, varname is not recognized as a1 or a2

Comment: I have a partial answer, use `eval(as.name(varname))` however this does not work with `summarise` for the first instance of varname. this is the code for the relevant part:     `df1 <- df %>%
      filter(eval(as.name(varname))!=1) %>%
      summarise_(varname = mean(eval(as.name(varname))))
    print(df1)`

Comment: @lmo The plan is for dplyr syntax to work with data.tables, fwiw: https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr Anyway, a somewhat data.tabley way: `rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2), id=TRUE)[, dcast(.SD, .id ~ ., fun.agg = function(x) mean(x[x!=1]), value.var = names(dt1))]`

Comment: @Amar when I tried your method I got the following error:  Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : object 'a1' not found

Answer (score 3):

For a purely `data.table` way, I would combine the different `data.tables` and compute the averages:

```
# Concatenate the data.tables: 
all_dt <- rbind("dt1" = dt1, "dt2" = dt2, idcol = "origin")
all_dt
#    origin a1 a2
# 1:    dt1  1  4
# 2:    dt1  2  5
# 3:    dt1  3  2
# 4:    dt2  1 52
# 5:    dt2 43  4
# 6:    dt2  1  1

# Melt so that "a1" and "a2" are labels in a group column:
all_dt <- melt(all_dt, id.vars="origin")
all_dt
#     origin variable value
#  1:    dt1       a1     1
#  2:    dt1       a1     2
#  3:    dt1       a1     3
#  4:    dt2       a1     1
#  5:    dt2       a1    43
#  6:    dt2       a1     1
#  7:    dt1       a2     4
#  8:    dt1       a2     5
#  9:    dt1       a2     2
# 10:    dt2       a2    52
# 11:    dt2       a2     4
# 12:    dt2       a2     1

# Compute averages by each data.table and column group, ignoring 1s:
all_dt[value != 1, .(mean = mean(value)), by = .(origin, variable)]
#    origin variable      mean
# 1:    dt1       a1  2.500000
# 2:    dt2       a1 43.000000
# 3:    dt1       a2  3.666667
# 4:    dt2       a2 28.000000
```

Comment: One downside is that when all rows for a var are 1, you'll have it omitted instead of NA.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution based on the comments of @Amar and @Scott Richie

```
for (d in ind) {
  df <- get(paste0('dt', d, sep=''))
  for (v in ind) {
    varname <- paste0('a', v, sep='')
    df1 <- df[eval(as.name(varname))!=1, .(mean = 
                                 mean(eval(as.name(varname))))]
    print(df1)

   }
 }
```

Thanks EVERYONE!

Answer (score 0):

Would go for a vectorised approach. You are using R!

One possible way:

```
require(dplyr)

dt1[dt1==1] <- NA #replace 1 with NA

dt1 %>% summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE) #mean of all columns. 

   a1       a2
1 2.5 3.666667
```

Comment: The actual problem I'm facing is more complicated than this one, where I do need to loop through data.tables and variables. I need to first filter out the observations where one variable ==0, and then I need to do some aggregation wrt another variable for the remaining observations.

Comment: I guess this might all be solved with vectorisation. The filter step easily done with dplyr::filter. Aggregation probably with summarise. But I probably do not entirely understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do, but if you want to replace all of the rows in the dataframe with the mean of the previous data frame's columns, I would suggest using a dataframe type instead as it is easier to index. Here is code that should work:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(a1 = c(1,2,3), a2 = c(4,5,2))
dt2 <- data.frame(a1 = c(1,43,1), a2 = c(52,4,1))

dtname = 'dt'
ind  = c('1', '2')
for (d in ind){
  df <- get(paste0('dt', d, sep=''))
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    for (j in 1:ncol(df)){
      if (df[i,j] !=1){
        df[,j]<- mean(df[,j])
      }
     }
    print(df)
  }
}
```

The reason your code was not working before was because the variables were being treated like strings, not actual variables. You can see this by printing the data type of variances:

```
dtname = 'dt'
ind  = c('1', '2')
for (d in ind) {
  df <- get(paste0('dt', d, sep=''))
  for (v in ind) {
    varname <- paste0('a', v, sep='')
    print(class(varname))
  }
}
```

Which just returns "character"

Another solution using variable names and the dataframe type would be to index the df as follows:

```
df[["varname"]]
```

Here are two helpful links for this kind of operation:
 
* [link 1: How to find the mean of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163863/r-need-help-to-calculate-the-mean-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame)

* [link 2: Data frames](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame)