# Loop over date to calculate means

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series

I have a data frame of dates from 2013 to 2018, with a daily precipitation value for a location I am studying. I want to calculate the mean precipitation of each date for the years mentioned above. For example, the mean precipitation on June 1 from 2013 to 2018. I will use this daily mean to then study the daily deviations from the mean daily precipitation from 2013 to 2018.

This is what my data looks like 
[DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZsKB.png)

I don't know how to write the loop for this, so I don't have any code to show.

The output for this loop should be a list of dates of the year with a long term mean for each date, something like below:

```
Date (dd/mm)    Mean
01-01           1.5
02-01           4.6
03-01             5
  .
  .
31-12            6
```

Thank you!

Comment: rather than add a screenshot, please `dput` your df and paste the code in your question so there's a reproducible data sample.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in a plethora of other posts. A combination of

1. Converting to date as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33408636/convert-column-in-data-frame-to-date)
2. Calculating the mean of a column in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163863/mean-of-a-column-in-a-data-frame-given-the-columns-name) and/or
3. Calculating grouped mean as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982987/mean-per-group-in-a-data-frame)

would answer your question.

I'll assume your dataTable is actually either a `data.table` or `data.frame`, and or shorthand I'll call the data `data`. I'll provide a `base` R version using `with` and `ave` function, and i'll provide an example with `data.table` using their subsetting option

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
#Data frame way
with(data, ave(Vil_481690, #variable to calculate mean 
               year(Vil_dates), #which variables to group (can be any number of variables)
               FUN = mean #already standard
               ))
#data.table way
setDT(data) #change data to a data.table
data[, mean(Vil_481690), by = year(Vil_dates)])]
```

Note these have not been tested as there was no copy-able data, so there might be typo one place or another.